# jQuery backgroundPostion and animate can't only get the Y

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem. I have this 3060 px wide image as my background-image, and when I press a menu link I want to 'slide' the background to the right or left, but when I'm doing this I can only get it to use the X. If I use backgroundPositionX, it doesn't do anything. When I use backgroundPosition, though, I can only provide 1 parameter. And I only want to do something to the X side not the Y.

The code I have at the moment sets the Y to 50% automatically, and this is not wanted.

```
        function move(space) {
            image = 3060;
            bodyWidth = $('body').width();
            offset = 900 * space;
            if(image - offset < bodyWidth)
                offset = image - bodyWidth - 15;

            console.log(offset);
            console.log(bodyWidth);


            $('body').animate({
                backgroundPosition:  -offset


            }, 5000, function() {
                console.log("animate complete");
            });

            //$('body').css('backgroundPosition', '-'+offset+'px 0px');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put both x and y coords in order for this to work.  Example:
Say you wanna move the background position from 0px to 500px on X.

```
$(somediv).animate({backgroundPosition: '500px 0px'})
```

Assuming the background original position is 0px*0px, this will move the background to X:500px and Y:0px.  Then you could bring it back like this:

```
.animate({backgroundPosition: '0px 0px'})
```

Comment: even if i backgroundPosition:  "500px 50px" the animation dosn't work. Only if i backgroundPosition:  offset or gives only 1 number it works.